# IS it safe to use window.location to query the GET params of a page?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm doing a peer review and I've found people using window.location.search to check what paremetes have been sent to a given (search) page.

Is it safe to do so? I was thinking that we could probably print the parameters in the HTML output inside a script block and verify the printed variables instead of querying window.location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to note about this approach.  `window.location` is set statically on page load and will not detect changes that the user has made to the address bar after that time.  This should not be a concern but it is important to know.

Save the following code as an html file and fire it up in a browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
                onclick="alert(window.location);">click me</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

The "click me" anchor will display the current window location `onclick`.  However if you add anything to the address bar and click the link again it will report the same thing it did the first time.

Hopefully this is not a concern and I cannot imagine that it would affect you in any way but it is good to know.

Answer (score 13):

If javascript is enabled, `window.location.search` is safe to use.

And just as some useless piece of further information: The property was as far as I know  introduced in Netscape Navigator 2 / MS Internet Explorer 3, so I'd say it's pretty safe to use, even if it's not part of any standard (yet).

Comment: It is part of the latest working draft for ECMAScript.  You should be pretty safe using it: http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#location

Comment: Is window.location.search still safe to use in 2017? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Safe as in 'security' or 'will this work always' ?

Even though window.location is widely it is still not part of the W3C standard. However it was added to the working draft spec in 2006: basically means a browser may or may not support it. So from a 'will this work always' you will be taking a small chance I guess.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to do so?

Yes. Example code to get parameters as a name->value map, assuming you don't need multiple values per parameter:

```
function getParameters() {
    var parameters= new Object();
    var parts= window.location.search.substring(1).split('\x26');
    for (var parti= parts.length; parti-->0;) {
        var subparts= parts[parti].split(';'); // support semicolon separators as well as ampersand (see HTML 4.01 section B.2.2)
        for (var subparti= subparts.length; subparti-->0;) {
            var parparts= subparts[subparti].split('=', 2);
            if (parparts.length==2)
                parameters[decodeURIComponent(parparts[0])]= decodeURIComponent(parparts[1]);
        }
   }
   return parameters;
}
```